# Category in search menu

Tags: geonetwork

I'm trying to configure GeoNetwork, v4.0. When registering a record, you can assign a category (or multiple categories), such as 'application', 'audio/video' etc. in the top bar. How can you add this 'category' field to the search menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this JSON code in the Admin console > User interface > customize Search application Facets configuration

Put this somewhere in the root of the JSON object, for example, above the `"resourceType": {`

```
  "cat": {
     "terms": {
     "field": "cat.keyword",
       "size": 22
     }
  },
```